# Scheme - Map function for applying a function to elements in a nested list

Tags: list, nested, scheme, map-function

I'm trying to write a mapping function in scheme that applies a function to each value in a nested list.

For example, `(map number? '(3 (2 A) 2 Z)` should return `(#t (#t #f) #t #f)`

Here's what I have so far:

```
(define (map fun lst)
    (if (null? lst) '()
        (if (list? (car lst)) 
            (cons (map fun (car lst)) (map fun (cdr lst)))
                 (cons (fun (car lst)) (map fun (cdr lst))))))
```

It works if the nested list is at the front of the list. For example `(map number? '((3 A) 2 Z))` correctly returns `((#t #f) #t #f)`

The problem occurs when the nested list occurs after another element in the original list.
For example `(map number? '(3 A (2 Z)))` incorrectly returns `(#t #f #f)` [The result should be `(#t #f (#t #f))`]

How can I change my algorithm to correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my solution---it's seriously cheap in that it reuses the built-in `map`, using the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). (I know, Scheme programs using design patterns? :-O)

```
(define (deep-map f l)
  (define (deep x)
    (cond ((null? x) x)
          ((pair? x) (map deep x))
          (else (f x))))
  (map deep l))
```

This can be "simplified" even further by using a named `let`:

```
(define (deep-map f l)
  (let deep ((x l))
    (cond ((null? x) x)
          ((pair? x) (map deep x))
          (else (f x)))))
```

(The two snippets of code are not identical, but for this question, both will work the same if given a list as input.)

The `null?` and `pair?` checks (both O(1)) are used in order to avoid using `list?` (which is O(n)).

Comment: "Seriously cheap" here is incorrect...  For example, I'd expect many implementations to produce better code for the simpler version that calls itself directly, since `map` is usually heavy enough to not be inlined.  So while it might be cheaper in some cases, claiming that it's always cheaper is wrong.

Comment: @Eli: "Cheap" isn't referring to performance in this context, but that I've taken the cheater's way out of the problem. :-)

Comment: CKY: it's not even cheaper in terms of reusing code -- you're saving on `(cons (map ...) (map ...))` which is a tiny advantage, but the result is clearer from a pedagogical POV...  (And in the process you get something that is more generic, though that of course is irrelevant for the question.)

Comment: @Eli: I responded on IRC. (Figured that it's the most straightforward way to get everyone on the same page.) :-)

Comment: Note that `pair?` does not imply a list - this will fail for `(a (b . c) d)`  with "(b . c) is not a proper list". 
You can't avoid paying that O(n) on `list?` since that's what `map` requires

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, except that it's way too verbose than it could be.  Hint: you need to worry about only two cases: whether `lst` is a `pair?` or not.  That's all.  In other words, your code assumes that the input is always a list, but it could be simplified to accept anything, and do the special recursive thing when it's a pair.

As for the problem that you're seeing -- my guess is that you're using Racket, and therefore you're running against an odd case.  If this is not the case then you can stop reading here.

The thing is that in Racket the function itself will compile before the binding to `map` is made, therefore the `map` calls are not really recursive, but instead they're just calls to the builtin `map`.  Later on, `map` is (re-)bound to the resulting function, but the recursive calls were already compiled.  If you enter the same definition twice, you'll see that it starts working again.  The way to solve this is to just not work at the REPL, and instead always write definitions in a file that starts with some `#lang <something>`.

Comment: I'm using Chicken. Thanks for your hint, I will try to fix it.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that Chicken does that, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's the same issue...

Comment: Sorry, but could you clarify what a pair is in the context of scheme? I'm still a newbie.

Comment: @user247679: Lists in Scheme are composed of zero or more conses (pairs). For example, `(list 1)` is the same as `(cons 1 '())` (list composed of one pair), and `(list 1 2 3)` is the same as `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))` (list composed of three pairs). In Scheme, you can test for pairs using `pair?`.