# Recursion on deep list scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I have created a function that takes a list as input and returns either a list or a atom. I want to apply this function to a deep list, starting with the inner lists, then finish once the function has been run on the outer list.

Can somebody give me some direction on this?

A sample input would be (a b (c (d e))) z) the function should compute on (d e) first with a result of say f. then the function should compute on (c f) with a result of say g then similarly on (a b g z) to produce an output of h.

An example function could be:

```
(define sum
 (lambda (l)
  (if (not (pair? l))
   0
   (+ (car l) (sum (cdr l))))))
```

Where input would be (1 2 (3 4) 5) > 15

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far, with sample inputs and expected outputs, outlining exactly where's the problem with your implementation

Comment: a sample input would be (a b (c (d e)))) the function should compute on (d e) first with a result of say f. then the function should compute on (c f) with a result of say g then similarly on (a b g) to produce an output of h. I can't paste my code as it's for homework.

Comment: @user234234 Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5699899/23567 which solves a similar problem. Without any code, people are more reluctant to help.

Comment: @seogaard thanks for your help so far, i appreciate that it may be hard to give me an answer without my code. I have looked at the question you have posted but the in the question, the function is computed on each element of the list rather than the list as a whole. Could you suggest a modification on this answer?

Comment: Mimic the structure of map-deep.

Comment: @seogaard i am still having problems could you have a look with the function i have added? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your example transformation, expressed as a Scheme procedure:

```
(define (transform lst)
  (case lst
    (((d e)) 'f)
    (((c f)) 'g)
    (((a b g z)) 'h)
    (else (error (~a "wot? " lst)))))
```

then what you are looking for seems to be

```
(define (f lst)
  (transform
   (map (lambda (e) 
          (if (list? e) (f e) e))
        lst)))
```

Testing:

```
> (f '(a b (c (d e)) z))
'h
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
(define product
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
      [(number? l) l]
      [(pair? l)   (* (product (car l)) (product (cdr l)))]
      [else        1])))

> (product '(1 2 (3 4) 5))
120
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help however i am looking to map the already defined function e.g. sum or another function to the deep-list.